# Remote Server File Access

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have employees asking me if they are able to access server files remotely?  I want to know if SharePoint 2010 may be configured to do this?  I would like to use avoid an expensive VPN solution if I can.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx) to access files remotely. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10026196 .

A different approach is to use [WebDav](http://support.sherweb.com/Faqs/Show/how-to-connect-to-a-sharepoint-site-using-webdav-sharepoint-2010).